# Deleting the records with condtion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am using SQL Server 2000

Table1

```
ID  Date

001 23/02/2009
001 24/02/2009
002 25/02/2009
....
```

Table2

```
ID  Date

001 23/02/2009
002 25/02/2009
```

Query Like

```
Delete from table1 where table1.id = table2.id and table1.date = table2.date
```

How to make a Query for the above condition

Comment: Why the down votes? This is clearly a question about how to use a secondary table as the the source for delete. The attempt made by OP was really close and 5 people have understood and tried to answer the question so it is at least "clear".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete table1
from table2
where table1.id = table2.id and 
      table1.date = table2.date
```

`delete table1` makes `table1` the target for deletion. You could write `delete from table1` but `from` is optional.

`from table2` specifies the source for deletion. To use a "second" from clause is a t-sql extension that is used to match corresponding rows.

Finally the where clause joins the tables on columns `id` and `date` causing the matching rows in `table1` to be deleted.

```
where table1.id = table2.id and 
      table1.date = table2.date
```

Comment: @markus Added an explanation of the delete command. Please let me know if I can help you to understand it further. You can find the documentation for delete here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Comment: Looks much better to me now! Thanks for the improvements!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT t1.ID 
              FROM TABLE1 t1 
                 INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Date = t2.Date)
```

This way you can run the select statement separately to see the data it will be deleting

Answer (score 1):

Using `exists` usually is better (faster):

```
delete t1
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also join the tables together for the delete:

```
DELETE FROM t1
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
   AND t1.Date = t2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in below ways:

a. Using Join Operation

```
DELETE FROM Table1
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
Table2 ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date AND Table1.Id = Table2.ID
```

b. Using WHERE clause

```
DELETE TABLE1
FROM TABLE2
WHERE Table1.Date = Table2.Date AND Table1.Id = Table2.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE
( SELECT table1.id, table2.id 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id and table1.date = table2.date )
```